# Matlab corrupting blob from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, matlab, blob

I have several blobs stored in MySQL (5.7.16, running on Linux).

When I retrieve these blobs with Matlab (2016b, MacOS, mysql-connector-java-5.1.40) some bytes are corrupted, making the original blob unusable.

The [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wszUV.png) contains an example. The left file is the corrupted one, as saved from Matlab. The right is the original, as saved from MySQL Workbench.

This is how I make the connection to the database:

```
conn = database('dbname','username','password','Vendor','MySQL','Server','localhost');
```

This is how I make the SQL query:

```
curs = exec(conn, 'SELECT FileContent FROM Table WHERE Id = 1;');
```

... and this is how I save the blob:

```
file = fopen(filename, 'wb');
fwrite(file, curs.Data{1}, 'uint8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugging reveals that `curs.Data{1}` is of type `int8`.

When saving use

```
fwrite(file, curs.Data{1}, 'int8');
```